# How to run contracts with 'Oraclize' using truffle?

Tags: contract-design, truffle, testrpc, oracles

This is the contract code.I have downloaded the 'Oraclize API' (oraclizeAPI_0.4.sol)from the Oraclize github repo.I have added this file to the truffle contracts folder, and rename the file to usingOraclize.sol.And it is imported in the given contract.

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

 import "./usingOraclize.sol";

 contract ApiCall is usingOraclize {

       uint public DieselPriceUSD;

       function DieselPrice() {

                OAR = OraclizeAddrResolverI(0x920cd3f7ed02c5d61e2556308d53a4d9d1e58bf2); 
       }

       function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result) {
                if (msg.sender != oraclize_cbAddress()) throw;
                       DieselPriceUSD = parseInt(result, 2); 
       }

      function update() payable {
                oraclize_query("URL", "xml(https://www.fueleconomy.gov/ws/rest/fuelprices).fuelPrices.diesel");
     }

}
```

I have compiled and deployed this contract succesfully.
Then tried to call the methods available using the following.

```
  contract.getCall().then(console.log);
```

But it returns the following error.

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid JUMP at 7ed62a9ee27ba25842c0facef792865de53617fe32c09b7eb974a8bca5dd54c0/b8cd3e9aaf13b8823aa83f0f47f235943dac31c6:692
```

How to call _callback function in this contract with the parameters?What these parameters in this _callback means?

How to use this _callback in index.js in truffle?

Comment: Which network did you deploy to?

Comment: @Xavier Lepretre B9lab I have used testrpc and truffle for this.

Comment: @Xavier Leprêtre B9lab  How to run _callback function using truffle?I didn't have any idea regarding the parameters passed in this _callback function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a problem here. You believe that your constructor is `function DieselPrice()`, while in fact it is not your constructor because your contract is called `contract ApiCall`.

So your `OAR` is always null.

Plus, Oraclize's Ethereum networks are only for test net and main net. Not TestRPC of course.

Comment: I have corrected the constructor.I have to use _callback function in my javascript file.So i have to pass the parameters to the _callback function.what are the parameters in _callback function?

Comment: Normally, Oraclize call you back on `__callback`, that's what they do and what you pay them for. Why are you calling `__callback`? Is it because you are doing tests?

Comment: I have no enough idea regarding it.Now i got the use of _callback function.It worked successfully using truffle and ethereum-bridge.